# Altium silkscreen art

Tags: altium, silkscreen

I'm trying to design a logo in silkscreen in Altium without importing an image. I find that when I import a design it is made up of a huge number of primitives making it very difficult to work with. Since my design is actually quite simple I would like to design it in Altium.

Essentially what I would like to do is create a square shaped silkscreen (done already done by placing a solid region on the top overlay) and then remove some text from that solid area. Essentially I'm looking for a silkscreen-keepout layer to draw onto.

Does this exist or is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could create a similar effect with four filled rectangles, of course.

Comment: Yes I ended up placing the text I wanted and then tracing around it using lines and then filling the space with the filled polygons.

Comment: When you imported an image, was it `visually` what you wanted? And just difficult to physically manage (i.e. move, resize)?

Comment: Yes, for the most part. The edges weren't very clean either but mostly it was made up of hundreds of primitives and very difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I ended up having to create my logo using only positive silkscreens. The easiest way to do this was to create the negative image I wanted and then trace around it with very fine silkscreen traces and then fill in the big blocks with silkscreen polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use inverted string?

see:
http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Obj-String((String))_AD

Comment: As far as I can tell this would work if my logo was only text and I wanted it in a font that is available.